# window.dataLayer push more key value in the same event

Tags: reactjs, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

In a ReactJS app, in the `root.tsx`, push an `event "website_pageview"` with `pageInfo`

```
        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: "website_pageview",
            pageInfo: {
                path: window.location,
                title: window.document.title,
            }
        });
```

In another route file `blog.tsx` which contains tags and authors, how can I push more key-value to the existing pageInfo in the same `event: "website_pageview"`?
I tried the following

```
        window.dataLayer[0].push({
            pageInfo: {
                tags: {categoryList},
                author: {authorList}
            }
        });
```

But it will return 2 entries as following when console.log `window.dataLayer``

```
(2)[
 {
   pageInfo: {
      tags: "Tag1, Tag2",
      authors: "Author1, Author2",
   }
 },
 {
   event: "website_pageview",
   pageInfo: {
      path: "https://google.com",
      title: "Page title",
   }
 }
]
```

What I want to achieve is the following. In GTM, based on the `event: "website_pageview"` it will trigger a `pageview` with all the needed info - path, title, tags, authors.

```
(1)[
 {
   event: "website_pageview",
   pageInfo: {
      path: "https://google.com",
      title: "Page title",
      tags: "Tag1, Tag2",
      authors: "Author1, Author2",
   }
 }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `window.dataLayer[0].pageInfo.tags = categoryList;`
`window.dataLayer[0].pageInfo.author = authorList;` ?

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration!

Because is a react app, the window.dataLayer[0] might not be related to the current page. 

Setting the array position of the dataLayer dynamically works:

window.dataLayer[window.dataLayer.length]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's okay that it's not in the same dataLayer array. Because in Google Tag Manager, it will combine it automatically in the `Datalayer Variable`

Here is the test result from you dataLayer :

---

1. I paste the dataLayer code in the console.

[image]

2. Create the `Datalayer Variable` in Google Tag Manager

[image]

3. We can see that the `test-Pageinfo` variable already merge all the parameters!

[image]